# Should I create a new thread as a class that extends Thread or just do a new Thread object instantiation?

Tags: java, multithreading, declaration

I just found out I could create a new thread with a simple

```
Thread myThread = new Thread() { 
   public void run() {}
}
```

But most books suggest I make a class that extends Thread, which seems a bit too much for me when I can just instantiate the Thread class directly. Is there anything wrong with my way of declaring a new thread over creating a new class?

Comment: You *have* made a class, it's just anonymous.

Comment: And is there anything wrong with my way of doing it?

Comment: There's no benefit to extending Thread unless you override something else as well as run(), so it isn't normally done. Use a Runnable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest not extending `Thread` itself at all. Instead, use the `Thread` overload which accepts a `Runnable`:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        ...
    }
});
```

You're not really changing the behaviour of `Thread` - merely giving it some code to run. That's more clearly represented by the code above than by subclassing `Thread`.

You should also consider using an `ExecutorService` instead of creating threads directly in the first place, mind you. That's another benefit of creating a `Runnable` - you're then flexible between passing it to a `Thread` constructor or using an `ExecutorService`... you can abstract out the `Runnable`-creation code, and then use whichever approach you want.

Comment: I would just add that extending Thread will prevent you from extending any other class. So simply create a new thread (creating an anonymous class) or make a class implement Runnable

Comment: @drewich: There's no indication that the OP *wants* to extend any other class here. In most cases I wouldn't even make another class implement `Runnable` - I usually implement that in an anonymous class.